# Is Vaadin 7 supporting table with pagination handled by server side?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I'm handling a lot of data and I would like to show it in my app. Is there is UI component, table with support of pagination on server site? So I can handle it via REST or some AJAX request.

Comment: I've used this addon https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/pagedtable to create paged tables.

Comment: As far as I see this is same story without lazy loading... I need mechanism to support ajax request.. not to load full data

Comment: Oh I see. I think you'd have to code your own paging. I did think about doing it myself as we have up to 6000 records to show on a table, but I found the pagedtable performed OK for us. All you would need to do is load up a table with the number of rows you wanted to show at a time, and create your own paging controls.

Answer (score 0):

Doing "traditional pagination" is pretty easy with Vaadin components (some layouts, labels and buttons). Here is an example how you can do it:

https://github.com/viritin/viritin/blob/master/src/test/java/org/vaadin/viritin/it/MTableWithTraditionalPaging.java

That example calls just some dummy data service, but you can naturally replace that with anykind of backend: for example JPA or accessing a remote REST service. It uses MTable from Viritin, but the same approach can be used with plain Table or Grid as well and in Vaadin 8 beta (with Grid) the usage is almost the same, just swap "setBeans" to "setItems".

If you want to list your stuff in a VerticalLayout, this add-on might also be helpful: https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/pagingcomponent